# How to create SPARK/Flink Stream Data Processing as a Microservice (REST API)

Tags: apache-spark, playframework-2.0, microservices, apache-flink, lagom

I am creating streaming analytics application using Spark, Flink & Kafka. Each analytics/functionality will implement as a Microservice so that this analytics can able to use in the different project later.

I run my Spark/Flink job perfectly in Simple Scala application and submit this job over Spark & Flink cluster respectively. But I have to start/run this job when REST POST startJob() request invoke to my web service.

How can I integrate my Spark & Flink data processing functionality in a web service oriented application?

Till now I tried [Lagom Microservice](http://www.lagomframework.com/) but i found so many issues you can check

1. [Best approach to ingest Streaming Data in Lagom Microservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255302/best-approach-to-ingest-streaming-data-in-lagom-microservice)
2. [java.io.NotSerializableException using Apache Flink with
   Lagom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570899/java-io-notserializableexception-using-apache-flink-with-lagom)

I think i am not taking the right direction for Stream Processing Microservice Application. Looking for right direction to implement this analytics over REST Service.

Answer (score 0):

Flink has a REST API you can use to submit and control jobs -- it's used by the Flink Web UI. See the [docs here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/monitoring/rest_api.html). See also [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724269/apache-flink-rest-client-jar-upload-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

I think the REST API provides job running details, Any Flink API provides suppose if Spring Boot REST end point call connects Kafka streaming data, and returns Kafka data?